# Running a sql query to csv file

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sqlcmd

Im trying to run a stored procedure and output the result to CSV. I am running this via the command line using the following command:

`SQLCMD -S SERVER/INSTANCE -E -Q "Exec DBNAME.STORED_PROCEDURE" -s "," -o "C:\temp\stats_data.csv"`

This works but with 2 problems.

**Problem 1)** I end up with whitespace around my headers, the library im using to import the CSV file later in my project can trim these out, but ideally I'd like them not to be there if possible.

example:

```
StatId     ,AsAtDate        ,PracticeCode        ,
          0,      2017-03-09,EMIS-170            ,
```

**Problem 2)** It outputs this row of "----" to separate the headers and data which is being treated as my first row of data when I try to parse in my project and throws an exception.

example:

```
StatId     ,AsAtDate        ,PracticeCode        ,
-----------,----------------,--------------------,
          0,      2017-03-09,EMIS-170            ,
```

Does anyone know how to solve either of these problems? My priority is the separator line (problem 2) as the first problem i can handle if need be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the first problem try to use `-W` parameter in your command line.